# Arduino Uno/Freeduino Serial Monitor reports that the connected WiFi Shield isn't present

Tags: arduino, wifi

I have connected my Uno (freeduino USB 1.1) to a wifi shield but when I run a program for network scanning, the serial monitor prints:

> WiFi shield not present

The code is here: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ScanNetworks

Shield is properly connected, LED named L9 lits up on powering up the board.

This is the wifi shield i'm using http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield

Comment: Please check your setup. Is your shield connected properly?

Comment: From the looks of it "WiFi shield not present" error message occurs when SPI comms with the shield fail. Has the shield ever worked? Have you connected other shields to the Freeduino?  Can you post a link to the exact product you have?  Taking out the shield, can you blink LEDs (don't forget current-limiting resistors!) on Arduino pins 10, 11, 12, and 13?

Comment: Is [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield) the WiFi shield you have?  If yes, maybe just edit that (including the link) into your question, and if no, just edit that (including the link to the product) into your question.

Comment: This is clearly *not a real question* since it is literally not a question.  Also, this seems to be a high level arduino user issue, not about electrical engineering.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Agree completely that it is *not a question*, but the Arduino part isn't why it's getting closed.